# Netbeans - Is it possible to change editor default programming language?

Tags: netbeans

I would like to edit file.html with javascript mark ups? Simple open my .html file as .js file.

Comment: If you use `<script>` tag in HTML file, you will get JavaScript syntax highligting, hints and other language specific goodies

Comment: good enough... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools|Options -> Miscellaneous|Files and for File Extension html change Associated mime type to text/javascript

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you probably can, but why would you want to edit an HTML file with Javascript markups/syntax highlighting? Whilst there is nothing preventing you doing it, it is not really good practise to have any significant amount of Javascript in an HTML file, so if you have a large amount it should be in a separate .js file

Comment: Yes, I would ... btw this is not really helpful "The answer is yes you probably can"...

Comment: You are asking what is called an XY question. This is a question where you are asking about X when your problem is probably Y. My answer is trying to point out that what you are trying to do is an indication that you are probably doing something wrong in terms of programming style. The comment by @dev_null_dweller above indicates for example that you might not be enclosing your Javascript in script tags

Comment: I'm writing app with symfony2, and because of this framework I can't play with file extensions.. basiclly I have one twig file which is loaded as text/javascript. All I need to do is to work with this file as js file. Second thing what I can do is to copy & paste js file to twig every save..

Comment: I've not used symfony2 but http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html seems to say you can use .js files. Your question should not be "how do I syntax hightlight JS in .html files" but instead "how do I access and use .js files in Symfony 2"?

Comment: No, my problem is a little bit different, my script src is loaded from server and so my html is here <script src="{ my.hmtl }"></script> and this html is loaded remotely, I can put there any extension by because of symfony2 this file is rendered from twig.